# Are methods DateTime.now() and new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis()) equal in java?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, java-time

I need to know, in java(my version jdk  8), i can replace, `new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis())` this code form , '`DateTime.now()`' ?

I used package `import org.joda.time.DateTime;`

How write this  same thing in  java 8 (date and time )  ?

Comment: Don't use the joda library with jdk8.  The java.time package in jdk8 is very similar to joda, so there's no point in having both.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem how to write this same thing in java 8 ?

Comment: The java.time equivalent of joda's DateTime class is called ZonedDateTime.  You want to write `ZonedDateTime.now()`.  But I think you should read up on the difference between `LocalDateTime`, `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime`, because there are similarities between all four classes, and you need to choose the right one for your particular needs.

Comment: Also you can pass a clock into an overload of the now method. Tests can provide a stub implementation of the clock so your test can specify a time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.Instant.now()  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

Internally, the moment is tracked as a count of whole seconds plus a fractional second as count of nanoseconds, since the epoch reference of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z (the `Z` means UTC).

## *java.time*

Your `DateTime` class is apparently from the Joda-Time library. The creator of that library, Stephen Colebourne, went on to replace Joda-Time with the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later, per JSR 310.

### `Instant`

For a moment in UTC, use `Instant`. To capture the current moment in UTC, `Instant.now()`.

`Instant` represents a count of nanoseconds since the epoch reference of the first moment of 1970 in UTC.

The call to `System.currentTimeMillis()` is the same, a count since start of 1970 UTC, except a more coarse resolution of milliseconds rather than nanoseconds. In practice, conventional computer clocks cannot accurately track the current moment in nanoseconds, so capturing the current moment with `Instant` may capture only microseconds (typical in Java 9 and later) or milliseconds (in Java 8).

The upshot: There is **no need to ever call `System.currentTimeMillis()`**. Use `Instant.now()` instead.

### `ZonedDateTime`

The equivalent of `DateTime` would be `ZonedDateTime`. This class represents a moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

[image]

Comment: `Instant` does not represent “a moment in UTC”. It represents a point of time, not affected by time zones at all.

Comment: @Holger Your point seems pedantic to me, and not at all useful to someone trying to learn the tricky subject of date-time handling. To my mind, a count of nanoseconds from the first moment of 1970 UTC is keeping track of time in UTC, is a moment in UTC. How is that *not* a moment in UTC? What utility does your point provide that escapes me?

Comment: *Especially* when trying to learn a tricky subject, it is important not to pollute a concept with inappropriate things. An `Instant` represents a moment in time, regardless of where in the world I am. An `Instant` is the first choice when I don’t want to deal with timezones. It is distracting to label something that is not connected to a timezone with “UTC”, which *is* a timezone. *Internally*, it is stored as a count from `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`, so the *reference value* is a *date* in the UTC timezone. The reference value for temperature has a pressure, still a temperature has no pressure.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8, [DateTime maps to](https://blog.joda.org/2014/11/converting-from-joda-time-to-javatime.html) `java.time.ZonedDateTime` and `java.time.OffsetDateTime`.

This page is written by the creator/author/maintainer of Joda Time and it recommends:

> If you are writing code in Java SE 8, its time to migrate to java.time...

Comment: can you  tell me how to take java 8 ,this same thing ? 'DateTime.now() ' or .'new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis())' ?

Comment: 'LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();  is this correct ?

Comment: @uma No, incorrect usage of `LocalDateTime`. That class cannot be used to track a moment as it lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. That class is irrelevant to the discussion on this page. I cannot imagine a case where it would be useful to call `LocalDateTime.now()`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
`new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis())` will call

```
public DateTime(long instant) {
    super(instant);
}
```

then

```
public BaseDateTime(long instant) {
    this(instant, ISOChronology.getInstance());
}
```

and `DateTime.now()` will call

```
public static DateTime now() {
    return new DateTime();
}
```

then

```
public DateTime() {
    super();
}
```

then

```
public BaseDateTime() {
    this(DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis(), ISOChronology.getInstance());
}
```

which is same as the first way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

This is the relevant code:

```
public BaseDateTime() {
    this(DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis(), ISOChronology.getInstance());
}
```

```
public BaseDateTime(long instant) {
    this(instant, ISOChronology.getInstance());
}
```